# Rotating multiple images in a circle using threejs

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I have an orbit which contains four images.These 4 images circle through this orbit,while each image takes a rotation of 360 degree itself.Eg:Earth rotates the sun while the earth itself rotate 360 degree.So what I want to do now is, I want the 4 images to circle through the orbit without the images undergoing rotation of its own.[image]

This is how I want the 4 images on the orbit to look even while it is rotating.
[image]

above image is where I found my issue.I don't want the images to be rotated as above.I want to keep the 4 four images like the first image I uploaded.
I am attaching my code for reference. Please help
**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-threejs-demo-basic-umcvaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts**

Comment: Your attached code has errors

Comment: Normally planes should not rotate on their own which is why this is confusing me. Are you adding them to another 3DObject and then rotating that? Which would rotate them as well

Comment: soory that was my mistake you are right plane should not rotate.i cleared this issue.thanks for the response.can you please help me in below part
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69377111/click-event-in-mesh-for-threejs